# How to show Locale List based on the Resource availability

Tags: android, locale

I am developing an application that fetches all the system available locales and show in a listview to be selected by user to change the application language(just like android's language change option).

But I have a few `res/values` folder in my application resources like values (default), values-bn, values-zh, values-ar. SO I want these 4 languages to be shown in the list. How can I do this? I need to do this programmatically.

Suppose, I have 4 folders `values, values-bn, values-en, values-zh`

Then I only show,

```
Bengali
English
Chinese
```

Comment: What would you expect it to say? The default `values` folder doesn't have to be in any specific language.

Comment: The default `values` folder will contain English. It will be used as backup if any string resource of available values folder (i.e. values-bn) is missing, it will be rendered from default folder

Comment: Then just hardcode in "English" at the start of the list. There is no way to auto-detect that English default, so you'll just have to fake it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) Yes, I've decided to hardcode it. But I thought there might be any better way to do it programmatically. Thats why I am waiting for. Now I am going to hardcode it as the resources are static and need to be changed rarely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what you want to do is have four languages: English, Bengali, Chinese, and Arabic, have I got that right? (Your question is internally inconsistent so it's hard to tell).

And you want to have a set of fallback values for when a string is missing in one of those four languages. The fallback values are in English, although the system won't know or care about that.

So what you want to do is put the strings for the four languages in the **values-en**, **values-bn**, **values-zh**, and **values-ar** directories and the fallback strings in the **values** directory.

In fact, since your fallback strings are in English, you could just put them in the **values** directory and have an empty resources file in the **values-en** directory. English would still show up in the list.

But why not just put the English versions of the strings in the **values-en** directory?

Comment: Thanks for your response :) The major query of my question is to - if there are three locale's values folder in my `res` directory, then How can I only show the three languages in the lists excluding the others which has no values folder?

Comment: Ahhh, different problem. Disregard my answer then. Why not just hard-code the list of known locales into your app. You'll have to modify the list every time you add a new locale, but that's not so bad is it?

Comment: Yes, I've decided it already. But I thought there might be any better way to do it programmatically. Thats why I am waiting for. Now I am going to hardcode it as the resources are static and need to be changed rarely.
Please edit your answer with this info of **hardcode** so that I can accept your answer. Thanks :)